# How to update in Vue3 component content based on reponse data?

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Recently I've been working on filters in my service for booking hotel rooms in .NET + Vue3.

Backend method for filtering works fine, but I don't have clue how to force component to update its content using fetched data.

1. Im reciving data in format like this:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9cRX.png)
   [image]
2. Here are my script and component files:

- Filters component:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <label for="first_day" class="p-2">First day: </label>
            <input type="date" name="first_day" v-model="filtersOptions.FirstDay" />

            <label for="last_day" class="p-2">Last day: </label>
            <input type="date" name="last_day" v-model="filtersOptions.LastDay"/>
            <button type="submit" class="m-2 p-2" v-on:click="fetchFilteredRooms()">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { useFilters } from '@/composables/useFilters';
    export default {
        setup(props: any, context: any) {
            const { filtersOptions, fetchFilteredRooms } = useFilters();

            return {
                filtersOptions,
                fetchFilteredRooms,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

- Filters script:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Consts from "@/consts";
import { useRooms } from './useRooms';

class FiltersOptions {
    FirstDay: any;
    LastDay: any;
};

const { Rooms } = useRooms();

export const useFilters = () => {
    const filtersOptions = ref<any>(new FiltersOptions());

    async function fetchFilteredRooms() {
        const filterRoomsAPI = Consts.API.concat(`rooms/search`)
        const headers = {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `${filterRoomsAPI}`
        }

        fetch(filterRoomsAPI, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            body: JSON.stringify(filtersOptions._value),
            headers
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => (Rooms.value = data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }

    return {
        Rooms,
        filtersOptions,
        fetchFilteredRooms,
    }
}
```

- Rooms component:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Consts from "@/consts";
import { useRooms } from './useRooms';

class FiltersOptions {
    FirstDay: any;
    LastDay: any;
};

const { Rooms } = useRooms();

export const useFilters = () => {
    const filtersOptions = ref<any>(new FiltersOptions());

    async function fetchFilteredRooms() {
        const filterRoomsAPI = Consts.API.concat(`rooms/search`)
        const headers = {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `${filterRoomsAPI}`
        }

        fetch(filterRoomsAPI, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            body: JSON.stringify(filtersOptions._value),
            headers
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => (Rooms.value = data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }

    return {
        Rooms,
        filtersOptions,
        fetchFilteredRooms,
    }
}
```

- Rooms script:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Consts from "@/consts"

const headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': `${Consts.RoomsAPI}`
}

export function useRooms() {
    const Rooms = ref([]);

    async function fetchRooms() {
        fetch(Consts.RoomsAPI, { headers })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => (Rooms.value = data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    return {
        Rooms,
        fetchRooms,
    };
}
```

Any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: Please show the data as code-formatted text and please add more text telling the details of your problem. Where in your code do you try to get the data into your front end and what problems *specifically* are you having in this attempt?

Comment: I'm no expert in JavaScript coding but I have to wonder if your code is not respecting the asynchronicity of the functions they hold. You seem to be returning from your fetchFilteredRooms and useRooms functions immediately before the asynchronous code has had a chance to retrieve anything. But again, I'm no expert in this. Perhaps your own use of callbacks would help with this.

Comment: 1. I'll do that
2. Thats's a good point, will look at it

Comment: Some of these links from this Google search might help you: [site:stackoverflow.com vue using asynchronous data](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vue+using+asynchronous+data)

Comment: Thanks, I will definately check it. Rn I found couple of issues in my concept of project so it might take a while